# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError while copying an object

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and running a little experiment on Chrome browser console. I encountered a problem as follows.

```
let obj = {a:1, b:2}
let obj2 = {...obj, [b]:8}
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined

This uncaught reference error is expected since I haven't defined `b` yet.

Then I tried `obj2 = 3`, I got an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: obj2 is not defined

When I tried `let obj2 = 3`, I got an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'obj2' has already been declared

I am really confused. Has `obj2` been declared or not and why do I get such errors?

Comment: It is really weird :) It looks like since you did not succesfully initialize obj2 (due to b is not defined error), it could not be a defined object. However, as you gave a name to it, it occupies a place in the namespace. Solution would be correcting the error and re-running the code but as you are in console refresing the browser and succesfully initializing the obj2 should solve the problem.